# Get longest List title name in array javascript Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint

I'm getting all the titles from my SharePoint site collection by this code. What I want is to find out which one of the list titles have the longest name,  and store the value in a *variable*:

This is the code I'm using to get the list titles:

```
while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) 
{
 var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
 listString += "<br>" + currentItem.get_title();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting all the titles from my sharepoint site collection by this code, what i want is to find out which one of the list titles have the longest name, in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare a length-storing variable outside your `while` loop, then within your `while` loop compare the length of the currently iterating `listString` with your length-storing variable:

```
var longest = "";

while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
        title = currentItem.get_title();

    listString += "<br>" + title;

    if (longest.length < title.length)
        longest = title;
}
```

When your `while` loop has finished iterating, the `longest` variable will hold the longest title.